# Is usage of specific weapons tracked by Bungie in Destiny 2 and is it available via the API?

Tags: destiny-2

Using [the API](https://bungie-net.github.io/multi/), you can get the usage stats for each weapon category (`weaponKillsHandCannon`, `weaponKillsSideArm`, `weaponKillsSubmachinegun`, etc.), broken down into game category (`patrol`, `raid`, `story`, `allStrikes`, etc.), but can you retrieve usage stats for specific weapons using [the API](https://bungie-net.github.io/multi/)?

I know it can be done for Exotic items.

On Destiny Tracker, specific weapons have “[PvP Weapon Insights](https://db.destinytracker.com/d2/en/items/3991544423-the-conqueror-2)” which lead me to believe each weapon is tracked individually, but I'm not interested in my PvP insights, only my PvE insights.

Comment: This feels like it would sit better over on StackOverflow to me, perhaps someone can migrate it?

Comment: @DavidYell I think gamedev might be more appropriate, not sure.

Comment: When you refer to usage, do you mean how many kills that specific weapon has gotten?

Comment: @Childishforlife I do.

Comment: It's not really a programming question, so it doesn't fit on SO. And from what I've seen it probably doesn't track every single weapon per user everywhere.